# PyMySQL throw "pymysql.err.Error: Already closed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

In PyMySQL, How to make `pymysql.connect` keep-alive forever ?

**OR**

How to check connect already closed before used.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `pymysql` code, at [this](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/f2e79cd1817a528b3f976ee1c79ab9d5bdf4324e/pymysql/connections.py#L724) line, you will see that the `connection` object has a property `open`:

```
@property
def open(self):
    return self._sock is not None
```

So, simply check if your connection is still open with this property:

```
myconn = connection(host,username,password,db)

if conn.open:
    # do your db management here
else:
    #connect again
```

Alternatively, you can catch the exception raised from hitting the DB where the connection was already close, this will throw an error code [2006](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_server_gone_error) (which you can also see in [this](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/f2e79cd1817a528b3f976ee1c79ab9d5bdf4324e/pymysql/constants/CR.py#L9) line):

```
try:
    cursor.execute(myquery)
except pymysql.OperationalError as e:
    if e.errno == 2006:
        #reconnect to server
```